# Create unique user for each test class run executing automation test

Tags: java, api, selenium, testng, ui-automation

I have implemented parallel testing using Selenium and TestNG for a web application, however, my webapp got a restriction where only one session can be handled at the time (it is not supporting multi-sessions, when you login with the same user it will disconnect your older session), the solution of which I have thought to solve it is to create a unique user for each test (using API), so I have implemented it but when I am running the tests in parallel (using testng.xml file with thread-count="2") I am creating the same user twice! with the same credentials, I want to be able to create a unique user where it will create one unique user for each run.

This is my code:

```
public class BaseApiTest extends BaseTest {
    protected String token;
    protected String CREATED_ADMIN_TEST_USER;
    protected String CREATED_ADMIN_TEST_PASSWORD;
    private static final AtomicReference<String> ACCESS_TOKEN = new AtomicReference<>();

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun=true)
    public void baseApiSetup() throws InterruptedException, ApiException {
        generateToken();
        createAdminUser();
    }

    private void generateToken() {
        ........
        ..........
        ...........
        token = "Bearer " + ACCESS_TOKEN.get();
        context.setAttribute("api-key", token);
        context.setAttribute("HOST", HOST);
        T_Logger.info("Host url address is: =[{}]", HOST);
        T_Logger.info("new api key token =[{}]", token);
    }

    private void createAdminUser() throws ApiException, InterruptedException {
        UsersAPIUnitTest usersAPITU = new UsersAPIUnitTest(context);
        usersAPITU.createUser();
        CREATED_ADMIN_TEST_USER = UsersAPIUnitTest.getEmail();
        CREATED_ADMIN_TEST_PASSWORD = UsersAPIUnitTest.getPassword();
    }


}
```

and this is used by the login page with the newly created user:

```
protected void adminSignIn() {
        loginPage.login(CREATED_ADMIN_TEST_USER, CREATED_ADMIN_TEST_PASSWORD, true);
        writeToLoggerSignIn(CREATED_ADMIN_TEST_USER);
    }
```

and then I am starting to run my tests.

**Expected**: each test class will contain its own unique user

**Actual**: all the users that are being created are the same user with the same credentials

========================**EDIT**===============================

This is how I create new user:

```
public String createUserCms(String name, String email, String phone, String password) throws ApiException {
        NewUserPayload body = new NewUserPayload();
        body.setStatus(true);
        body.setName(name);
        body.setEmail(email);
        body.setPhone(phone);
        body.setPassword(password);
        body.setPasswordConfirmation(password);
        printBody(body);
        return usersApi.createUser(token, body);
    }
```

Comment: where you are calling `createUserCms()` and are you passing unique `name` and `email` every time you make a call to this method?

Comment: I am calling it from adminSignIn() method which is being called from BaseApiTest and this is how I implement it:

public void createUser() throws InterruptedException, ApiException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        String response = usersAPI.createUserCms(userName, email, phoneNumber, password);
        Assert.assertEquals(response, "User Created Successfully");
        System.out.println(response);
//        T_Logger.info("User =[{}] created successfully with password=[{}]", userName, password);
    }

Comment: As for passing username and password , I am using the same user which creates the token for which I can use further to create a new user, so actually I am using the same user time after time and this user is creating the various unique users.

Comment: Got it! `UsersAPIUnitTest.getEmail()` is this method returning the new user?

Comment: To get the newly created email for the user but yes this is my user-name with this email I can sign in.

Comment: Any update how to do it? @supputuri

Comment: Sorry, I am a little confused. I see you have `createUser()` without any params in the  `createAdminUser()` method, but in the `createUserCms()` you have the params for `createUser()` method. So, do you have method overloading implementation for `createUser` and does the `UsersAPIUnitTest.getEmail()` will return the new user email address or the super user that you are using to create the users?

Comment: If you want we can open a room and discuss about it... as you understand I did not share all my code here...

Comment: Sure, please create a room and we can discuss it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a generic solution for this problem so that all automation teams can use it, still work in progress. I'm sure you would have explored other options, but creating users every time you run a test is not a good idea, rather you have to create the users once and use them otherwise you end up adding more users into your system (if you are cleaning up the users `@afterMethod` that's fine)

But for now, in your case, you have to make sure that you pass a unique name/email when creating the user and return that username/email address.

If you can share your createUser method snippet, we can help you more.

Comment: Yes of course I will add it to my question , in general I used swagger to implement creation of my user (it is the webapp internal API for creation of new users), I will put it under EDIT, and BTW I do plan to delete every unique user after the test is finished